# Error while Renaming AD user using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am having the below code which I am using for Renaming the `cn` of the user

```
$path = "OU=Accounts,OU=IT,OU=$dcs1,DC=z,DC=if,DC=ag,DC=net" 


$ExportPath=@()
$Result=@()

$ExportPath = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like 'clean1_*'" -SearchBase $path | select -First 1

foreach($Usr in $ExportPath)
{

    Rename-ADObject -Identity $Usr -NewName {$Usr.Name -replace '^clean1_'} 
 
}
```

it is executing the making changes in AD like below. Original `Name` was `clean1_Reena_K (W00-198)`

[image]

Please let me know on this

Comment: Change `-NewName {$Usr.Name -replace '^clean1_'}` to `-NewName $($Usr.Name -replace '^clean1_')`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Tried the same. No changes. It is giving the same output in AD

Comment: well, the pattern no longer matches the new (wrong) name the object has. Manually rename it back to `clean1_rest_of_username`, then run it again and you'll see it works

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Just tried that way. executed without issue but no changes made. still name contains `clean1`

Comment: Are you changing the name on one DC and looking for changes on a different DC perhaps? Sometimes, things take time to synchronize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are replace `clean1_Reena_K (W00-198)` value into `Reena_K`.

#### Follow the Work around to fix:

#### Way 1:

For that you have to use the **Regex** to **find and replace**.

```
# syntax 
# String -replace -replace  ([regex]::Escape('<Text to find in string >')),'<Replace text>'

'$Usr.Name' -replace  ([regex]::Escape('clean1_')),''
```

#### Way 2

In an **Identity** you have to keep the **DistinguishedName**. As per I have slightly changed your code

```
$path = "OU=Accounts,OU=IT,OU=$dcs1,DC=z,DC=if,DC=ag,DC=net" 
$ExportPath=@()
$Result=@()

$ExportPath = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like 'clean1_*'" -SearchBase $path | select -First 1

foreach($Usr in $ExportPath)
{
     $DistName = $Usr.DistinguishedName
     $CName = $Usr.Name
     $newName = ([String]$CName).Replace("^clean1_","")
    
     Rename-ADObject -Identity $DistName -NewName $newName
 
}
```